# Nodejs built in modules implementation

Tags: node.js

Where can I find the implementation of node.js built in modules? I couldn't find inside node_modules folder.

Comment: Most of it is in https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can find it in,

> C:\Users\<**user**>\AppData\Roaming\npm